# Creating nested loops or functions

Tags: python, nested

Is it possible to create a chain of loops or functions that are all nested within another. Using an if statement as an example, I want to chain...

```
if x == 0:
    print(x)
```

while nesting them like this...

```
if x == 0:
    print(x)
    if x == 0:
       print(x)
       if x == 0:
           print(x)
```

How can I do this using an automatic process?
The code I want to do this to is:

```
    oglist = ["a","b","c"]
combolist = ["lol"]
comboloop = True
combocounter = 3
recursions = {}
for counterx in range(1, combocounter):
    recursions["recursion" + str(counterx)] = False
def loopgen(counter2):
    if counter2 == 0:
            def loop():
                global comboloop
                global recursions
                if len(lists["list0"]) == 0:
                    comboloop = False
                    recursions["recursion1"] = True
                else:
                    lists["list1"] = lists["list0"][1:]
                    recursions["recursion1"] = False
                return
    elif counter2 != combocounter - 1:
            def loop():
                global recursions
                if len(lists["list" + str(counter2)]) == 0:
                    lists["list" + str(counter2 - 1)] = lists["list" + str(counter2 - 1)][1:]
                    recursions["recursion" + str(counter2)] = True
                    recursions["recursion" + str(counter2 + 1)] = True
                else:
                    lists["list" + str(counter2 + 1)] = lists["list" + str(counter2)][1:]
                    recursions["recursion" + str(counter2 + 1)] = False
                return
    else:
            def loop():
                global counter3
                global recursions
                if len(lists["list" + str(counter2)]) == 0:
                    lists["list" + str(counter2 - 1)] = lists["list" + str(counter2 - 1)][1:]
                    recursions["recursion" + str(counter2)] = True
                else:
                    combolist[counter3] = lists["list0"][0]
                    for x in range(1, combocounter):
                        combolist[counter3] = combolist[counter3] + lists["list" + str(x)][0]
                    combolist.append("lol")
                    lists["list" + str(counter2)] = lists["list" + str(counter2)][1:]
                    counter3 += 1
                    recursions["recursion" + str(counter2)] = False
                return
    return loop
lists = {}
for x in range(0, combocounter):
    lists["list" + str(x)] = ["lol"]
loops = {}
for counter1 in range(0, combocounter):
    loops["loop" + str(counter1)] = loopgen(counter1)
lists["list0"] = oglist
counter3 = 0
while comboloop == True:
    loops["loop0"]()
    while recursions["recursion1"] == False:
        loops["loop1"]()
        while recursions["recursion2"] == False:
            loops["loop2"]()
combolist.remove("lol")
print(combolist)
```

There are only 3 while loops on the bottom, because `combocounter = 3`
In future versions of this, combocounter will not be a static number.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you're actually trying to solve? this is pretty unclear as is. What is real problem you're trying to solve that lead you to wanting a solution like this?

Comment: What you're describing sounds an awful lot like a while loop :)

Comment: I want the scope of functions or loops to be dynamic

Comment: This is a great example of the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

I'm not certain what you think you're doing, but I am 100% certain that you don't need to do this.

Comment: Python has really "weak" scoping rules. You can simply have all your `loop` defined and store it into another global variable.

Answer (score 0):

While loop :

```
while x == 0:
    print(x)
```

Recursion :

```
def f(x):
    if x == 0:
        print(x)
    f(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined another function which would replicate the creation of a while loop inside another while loop with...

```
def otherloop(counter4):
    while recursions["recursion" + str(counter4)] == False:
        loops["loop" + str(counter4)]()
        if counter4 != combocounter - 1:
            return otherloop(counter4 + 1)
    if counter4 != 1:
        return otherloop(counter4 - 1)
    return
```

Then of course I replaced

```
while recursions["recursion1"] == False:
    loops["loop1"]()
    while recursions["recursion2"] == False:
        loops["loop2"]()
```

with

```
otherloop(1)
```